# Perché a volte si utilizza la V per scrivere la U?

Tags: orthography

Qualcuno conosce il motivo per il quale a volte viene utilizzata, a livello grafico, la lettera V per indicare la U? Come, ad esempio, "Palazzo di Givstizia"

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carattere_lapidario_romano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

È vero che l'utilizzo della "V" al posto della "U" deriva dal latino, in cui le due lettere non erano distinte; secondo Wikipedia questa distinzione viene introdotta nel Rinascimento (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/U). 
Ed è altrettanto corretto che scritte come ""Palazzo di Givstizia" si trovano in palazzi costruiti in epoca fascista: questo "stile" faceva parte di tutta la simbologia antico-romana del regime come il fascio littorio e il saluto romano.

Comment: Non sono sicuro che quello stile sia necessariamente riferito al ventennio, tanto è vero che lo stemma ufficiale italiano ha “REPVBBLICA ITALIANA”.

Comment: @egreg la tua osservazione è interessante e mi ha fatto riflettere. Intanto segnalo che qui http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/u/ c'è una storia più completa della lettera "U".

Comment: @egreg Nel ventennio si è sicuramente diffusa questa "moda" per dare un'aria di "antica solennità", ma - anche se non trovo al momento esempi - è possibile che fosse utilizzata anche in precedenza. 
Per quanto riguarda lo stemma della Repubblica, sarebbe interessante scoprire cosa ha portato a quella scelta. Io credo che sia stata dettata sia dall'esigenza di dare un segnale di continuità (non dimentichiamo che i funzionari dello Stato nominati durante il ventennio non sono scomparsi da un giorno all'altro) che per conferire solennità.

Comment: Credo che all'epoca si cercasse di dare, semmai, “segnali di discontinuità”: proprio perché molti funzionari (e altri titolari di cariche di rilievo) lo erano fin dal Ventennio, cercavano di rifarsi una verginità ripudiando il ripudiabile. Direi che questa risposta abbia bisogno di fonti e di una maggior completezza. Grazie a @egreg per l'osservazione sullo stemma.

Comment: Molto interessante. Ma se le due lettere non erano distinte, come si faceva con parole tipo "avunculus"? Scrivevano "avvncvlvs"? Con la doppia "v"?

Comment: @MassimoTermanini Sì, esattamente

Comment: Mi è tornata sott'occhio questa domanda e ho controllato: la [tomba di Vittorio Emanuele II](https://images.app.goo.gl/uBSSq5SKazxrZg7G6) ha la “V” e risale certamente a molto prima del ventennio.

Comment: Ho sempre creduto che l'usanza fosse nata per semplificare la scrittura sul marmo, quando ancora non si usavano carta e penna.

Answer (score 4):

L'idea è di solennizzare adoperando lo stile delle iscrizioni romane e non ha nulla a che vedere con il fascismo. Per esempio, questa è la tomba di Vittorio Emanuele II al Pantheon

[image]

[Immagine a più alta risoluzione](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Tomb_Vittorio_Emanuele_II%2C_Pantheon%2C_Rome%2C_Italy.jpg)

Non sono riuscito a trovare la data precisa della traslazione nella tomba monumentale, ma il Pantheon fu designato come sede delle tombe reali nel 1878, quando morì Vittorio Emanuele II. Trovo anche, su https://www.vatican.va/various/basiliche/san_pietro/it/basilica/interno.htm

> Il gruppo scultoreo della Pietà fu eseguito da Michelangelo ancora ventitreenne. Terminata nel 1499, la Pietà apparve subito un capolavoro assoluto, ancor più sorprendente per uno scultore così giovane. Sulla cintura è incisa la firma per esteso, un particolare, come ricordò Benedetto Varchi nell'orazione funebre per l'artista, mai più ripetuto nelle opere successive: MICHAEL ANGELVS BONAROTVS FLORENT(inus) FACIEBAT.

Dubito che si possa tacciare Michelangelo di simpatie per il ventennio (vedi oltre). Che il fascismo abbia incrementato l'uso di questo stile non è affatto certo.

Naturalmente si troverà PALAZZO DI GIVSTIZIA o QVESTVRA con tutte lettere maiuscole, mai minuscole. Per quanto sia probabile che i Romani avessero una scrittura “corsiva” non credo esistano documenti scritti che la provino. Il minuscolo moderno nasce con le scritture cancelleresche dell'alto medioevo a in esse la V veniva resa con due barre unite sul fondo come nell'immagine che segue

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Caroline_2.jpg

Da questa scrittura viene la moderna “u” con la distinzione da “v”, ma si deve aspettare il Rinascimento (e questo spiega l'ortografia usata da Michelangelo). La distinzione fra “u” e “v” è diventata standard anche nelle edizioni moderne di opere latine; quella fra “i” e “j” è praticamente sparita, anche se ha lasciato il segno in nomi come Jules e Julius.